# Чем хорош Sublime Text 2?

Tags: sublime-text

В последнее время всё чаще слышу про этот редактор. Те, кто пользуется (или пользовался), расскажите, что такое уникально функциональное в нём есть?

---

*Комментарий к лучшему ответу. Выбрать было трудно (они все правильные же), поэтому победил самый впечатляющий ответ со ссылкой на презентацию возможностей редактора в 6 кадрах.*

Comment: уникального ничего, обычный редактор

Comment: Ну автоматизация, к примеру.

Comment: по умолчанию в этом редакторе нет подсветки синтаксиса паскаля, надо отдельно где то искать и ставить(

Comment: @Merlin, нет подсветки синтаксиса паскаля? Ужас то какой!!!

Comment: @LightShock Ваш сарказм не информативен и бесполезен, не засоряйте форум флудом.

Comment: @Merlin - тоже самое я хотел написать про ваш коммент про паскаль... :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Из особенностей: миникарта, множественное выделение и редактирование. Это то, что действительно отличает его от других редакторов. В общем-то, все фичи можно [посмотреть в шести "кадрах" презентации](http://www.sublimetext.com/). А вообще, [[@AlexWindHope](/users/3545/alexwindhope)](/users/3545/alexwindhope) прав - надо брать и пробовать. А уж подойдёт или нет - решите по ходу испытаний.

Comment: Мне безумно нравиться как там реализован скрол. Да и вообще - пользовательский интерфейс. Несмотря на то, что он весь няшный и анимированный - работает замечательным образом даже на довольно стареньких машинках. В общем - разработчики молодцы :)

Ну и карта, порой, тоже - действительно полезна ( как минимум - красива ) и, что немало важно - тоже ни грамма не тормозит

Comment: @AlexWindHope, абсолютно согласен. Плюс ко всему, если кому будет интересно, как писать плагины под этот редактор, то для старта, можно пробежаться по статейке "[Пишем простой плагин для Sublime Text 2](http://habrahabr.ru/post/136529/)"

Comment: Добавлю еще, что многое о редакторе может сказать его чейнджлог http://www.sublimetext.com/2

Comment: И еще можно добавить - если имели дело с textmate, это чудо точно для вас :)

Answer (score 3):

Он просто сделан *с душой* ( как хотите так и понимайте, не попробовав - не поймете ), банально очень приятно с ним работать, ничего экстраординарного в нем нет, он прост классный :D

Есть огромное множество плагинов, к тому-же, вы сами легко можете их писать ( использую Python или, установив необходимый плагин, sublime-v8 называется, если не ошибаюсь, JavaScript ).

---

К тому-же

- Довольно дружелюбное и большое сообщество ( хотя это и не так важно для редактора, но тем не менее - это все-равно большой плюс )
- Работа над редактором не прекращается никогда и редактор становиться только лучше, что, к сожалению, бывает крайне редко, чаще всего что-то делают, но зачем и кому оно нужно неясно ( отзывчивость разработчиков в вопросах новых фич не может не радовать )
- разработчики крайне внимательны к мелочам

PS: бесполезно кого-то слушать или что-то вычитывать, выдумывать. Просто возьмите и попробуйте сами.

Answer (score 2):

Обычный скриптуемый текстовый редактор со стандартными улучшениями для работы с кодом. Ничего особо плохого, но и ничего особо выдающегося.

- Гламурный и вполне продуманный UI, тут не пожалуешься. Keyboard-driven. Это плюсы. Минус — модлайн, насколько я знаю, не настраивается. Максимум что можно — выводить в «пустое пространство» на несколько секунд текст.
- С кодом работает нейтрально-посредственно. Сам по себе, без плагинов, «видит» только текст и TextMate-совместимым лексером (плюсы — часто легко найти bundle для хайлайта, минусы — некоторые вещи невозможно или очень сложно нормально подсвечивать) его раскрашивает. Для Python, например, расширением может подружиться с Rope (который уже работает, как положено инструменту для работы с кодом, с AST, а не текстом), соответственно, получить его плюшки рефакторинга. С другими языками — как повезет.
- Скриптуется на Python с соответствующими плюсами и минусами подхода. Редактор статически слинкован со старым libpython (2.6.6-final).
- С плагином ограниченно может в REPL, но, в общем-то, не больше чем пайпа с хайлайтером. Любители могут поискать счастья с эмулятором терминала (SublimePTY).
- С плагинами есть ограниченная поддержка отладчиков (качество зависит от языка), но, в связи с возможностями редактора, не больше хоткеев, подсветки строк и CLI. Если только кто-то сильно не извратится и не приделает сбоку отдельное окно визуализации, с GUI. Но лучше не надо.
- Проприетарщина, с nag-screen'ом, за шестидесятку на пользователя.

YMMV.

Comment: - "модлайн" настраивается.

Comment: Как? Если что, я про [modeline в терминах Emacs](http://www.emacswiki.org/ModeLine), а не [Vim](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#modeline). Статусбаре, в общем. Т.е. SublimeModeline — не то.

Upd: Нашел `View.{get,set,erase}_status`. Редактирование текста через запятую, можно добавить его в пустое пространство, справа к «Line X, Column Y». Или слева (про это не знал, да), если ключ будет меньше. Не более того.